# How do you file taxes earlier than an identity thief?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, identity-theft

One of the recommendations to avoid tax return fraud/identity theft is to file your taxes as early as possible:

- [FTC](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2017/09/equifax-data-breach-what-do)
- [Smart Money](https://www.smartaboutmoney.org/Topics/Insurance-and-Taxes/Tips-for-Filing-Taxes/File-Taxes-Early-to-Prevent-Identity-Theft)
- [Identity Theft Resource Center](http://www.idtheftcenter.org/Identity-Theft/the-importance-of-filing-taxes-early.html)
- [USA Today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/columnist/2016/01/30/what-irs-isnt-telling-you-identity-theft/79306984/)
- Notably, the IRS does not include this in their [list of recommendations](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/taxpayer-guide-to-identity-theft); they recommend protecting your information, as well as watching for signs of fraud and reporting it.

It seems to me that you will never beat a fraudster at their own game.

- You are concerned with the accuracy of your return. A fraudster just wants to get the maximum refund.
- You have to wait for documents to arrive, e.g. from your employer, bank, brokerage, and dependent's day care provider. The fraudster just needs a W-2.
- You have a day job and family responsibilities. Defrauding you and the IRS is the scammer's day job.

It seems to me that you can never file your taxes faster or sooner than a fraudster. So, how is this advice useful?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I agree, it is not a great suggestion.

The idea for it comes from the fact that a tax return can only be e-filed for an individual once.  If a second tax return is attempted to be e-filed, it will come back with an error.  Obviously, if you file your return earlier rather than later, it closes the window of when a fraudster can e-file a fake return for you.

However, as you said, there are lots of reasons why you should not file the return before you are really ready.

If the fraudulent return does get filed before you get around to your real one, it's not the end of the world.  When you try to e-file yours, you will get an error that a tax return has already been filed for you.  That will be your indication that there was a problem.  The [IRS knows that this happens](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/taxpayer-guide-to-identity-theft) a lot, so if you contact them and explain the problem, they will tell you what to do.  (It will probably involve mailing in your tax return along with [IRS Form 14039](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f14039.pdf).)

Comment: Is it possible/feasible to immediately file electronically and then file an amendment once you actually have the required information?

Comment: From a logistics point of view, no, because filling incorrectly is very different than dealing with fraud.  Filling incorrectly is your fault, whereas fraud is someone else's fault.  The process for fixing incorrectly filed tax returns are very different than the process for dealing with a fraudulent claim.

Comment: @RobP. That would not be recommended.  When you e-file, you are affirming that what you have sent is accurate to the best of your ability.  Knowingly submitting a false tax return with the idea that you would correct it later is not legal.

Comment: @BenMiller If you get the correct information from your own records (bank statements, pay stubs, etc.) before someone sends you their opinion, that is not fraud, even if you make a mistake.

Comment: @DavePhD Admittedly, I don't e-file, and when you mail in your form, you are required to submit copies of your W-2s, so I have to wait until I receive those.  However, in my opinion, it is not worth it to jump the gun and file your taxes early, knowing that you will likely have to amend it, just to attempt to thwart the possibility of someone filing a fraudulent return.

Comment: @BenMiller I don't e-file either and I accidently forgot to attach the W2 for 2015. IRS sent me a letter and I sent the W2 later.  There is no reason that needing to amend would be likely.  The people generating the W2s and 1099s could make a mistake too.

Comment: @DavePhD I don't disagree, but my first response was to RobP, who suggested "immediately" e-filing an incomplete return with the idea that you would correct it with an amendment later.  In my opinion, that would only set yourself up for hassle and scrutiny from the IRS with very little actual benefit.

Comment: @BenMiller I agree, you need the correct information.  Waiting until December bank and brokerage statements arrive, and the final paystub of the year, is necessary.

Comment: In addition to “closing the window”, it also provides you with an earlier notification that something foul is afoot.

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% foolproof, but it seems to be reasonable advice.

I file my taxes as soon as I can if I'm getting a refund, and closer to April 15th if I owe taxes. So if I get W-2s in early February, and I file in mid-February, that's only a 2-3 week window for someone to beat me to the punch.

So to say that you will *never* beat an identity thief seems too absolute. The pain (for you and the IRS) of dealing with return fraud is a decent incentive to file early, but you also want to make sure that your return is accurate and you have fully taken advantage of all deductions. I would certainly not rush the process just to try and front-run ID thiefs.

Comment: If you owe money, I think you can specify the date that they should take the money from your bank or credit card. So you can file early and tell them to take the money close to April 15.

Comment: Admittedly, the longer you wait, the larger the window. An extreme example is someone who was waiting until October 16th (automatic extension date this year) and was included in the Equifax hack.

Comment: D Stanley, if you often owe (significant) taxes, aren't you paying estimated taxes quarterly anyway?

Comment: @MattChambers not necessarily. Happened to me once when I converted a rollover 401(k) to a Roth IRA.

Comment: @stannius Same here - I took advantage of the two-year conversion offer and had significant tax due the first year (but no penalties)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the suggestion is saying "If you file the moment it's possible, you will beat all thieves".  That's absurd on its face, particularly as the thief can file *before* your W2 is available to you.

However, if you assume you're a random target, then thieves will be presumably filing returns over the entire January-April timeframe.  Making sure to file during the earliest reasonable window will decrease the threat envelope, meaning you have a reduced likelihood of having a fraudulent return filed using your information.